Relationship between temperature and mass dimension in AdS/CFT
I've been reading Hartnoll et. al.'s paper on holographic superconductors, specifically PRL 2008 https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.101.031601. In the paper, they mention "Recall that $T$ (temperature) has mass dimension one". What did they mean by this? Is this a consequence of choosing $G=\hbar=c=1$, or does it have something to do with the BF bound for mass?

Hint: In thermal qft’s  euclidean time is periodic in the inverse temperature of the system so you can derive the mass dimension of $T$ from that of euclidean time.
